# Converting FPS ground camera to FPS free flying camera

Tags: c#, opengl

I have implemented a camera in my OpenGL(openTk) project

```
      //Move(0f, 0.1f, 0f); }    Forward
      //Move(-0.1f, 0f, 0f); }   Left
      //Move(0f, -0.1f, 0f); }   Back
      //Move(0.1f, 0f, 0f); }    Right
      //Move(0f, 0f, 0.1f); }    Up
      //Move(0f, 0f, -0.1f); }   Down
    public static void Move(float x, float y, float z)
    {  
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3();
        Vector3 forward = new Vector3((float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.X), 0, (float)Math.Cos((float)Orientation.X));
        Vector3 right = new Vector3(-forward.Z,0,forward.X);
        offset += x * right;
        offset += y * forward;
        offset.Y += z;
        offset.NormalizeFast();
        offset = Vector3.Multiply(offset, MoveSpeed);
        Position += offset;
    }
```

Where "Orientation" is the x,y of the direction the camera is facing. "Position" is the position of the Camera in the world, and "MoveSpeed" is float.

This camera works great. But it is ground based. By this I mean that only the x value of the camera orientation affects movement direction. The y value does not. I want to make a free flying camera so if you look up and press forward the camera will fly into the air.

I tried changing the forward declation to:

```
Vector3 forward = new Vector3((float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.X), (float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.Y), (float)Math.Cos((float)Orientation.X));
```

This partially works, the camera now can fly into the air. But its not right, the camera is moving the same forward amount no matter how far "up" you tilt it. The up is not replacing some of the forward, its being added onto it.

I hope this explanation makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
First get the `forward` vector from `Orientation` (you can use this for your Camera.LookAt as well)

```
public Vector3 getForward(Vector2 Orientation)
{  
    Vector3 forward = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    //X axis rotation
    forward.Z = (float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.Y);
    forward.Y = (float)Math.Cos((float)Orientation.Y);
    //Z axis rotation
    forward.X = forward.Y*(float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.X);
    forward.Y = forward.Y*(float)Math.Cos((float)Orientation.X);

    return forward;
}
```

And then move your camera with:

```
public void Move(float horizontal, float strafe)
{  
    Vector3 forward=getForward(Orientation);
    //forward vector projected on XoY plane and rotated 90 degrees
    Vector3 leftXoY = new Vector3(-forward.y ,forward.x,0);

    Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.Multiply(forward,horizontal)+Vector3.Multiply(leftXoY,strafe);
    moveDirection.Normalize();

    Position += Vector3.Multiply(moveDirection,MoveSpeed);
}
```

So if you call `move(1,-1);` will move the camera forward (along the `forward` vector) and strafe right.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. This does not work for me, the right and left strafing is not handled in this one.   After fiddling with it for a long time I finally got it. See my answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after fiddling with it for a long time. I do not know if this is an efficient way to do it or not but it does work.

```
 public static void Move(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        Vector3 CameraTargetVector;
        CameraTargetVector.X = (float)(Math.Sin((float)Orientation.X) * Math.Cos((float)Orientation.Y));
        CameraTargetVector.Y = (float)Math.Sin((float)Orientation.Y);
        CameraTargetVector.Z = (float)(Math.Cos((float)Orientation.X) * Math.Cos((float)Orientation.Y));
        Vector3 offset = new Vector3();
        offset += x * new Vector3(-CameraTargetVector.Z, 0, CameraTargetVector.X);
        offset += y * CameraTargetVector;
        offset.Y += z;
        offset.NormalizeFast();
        Position += Vector3.Multiply(offset, MoveSpeed);
    }
```